# How can I compare two response ratios in meta-analysis?

Tags: variance, meta-analysis, effect-size

For example, there are several studies about how males and females response to certain condition.

Here's the data I got:
Xmc, the mean data of male control group, Xfc, the mean data of female control group,

Xmt, the mean data of male treatment group, Xfm, the mean data of female treatment group,

and I also got the Nmc, Nfc, Nmt, Nfm as the number in the groups,

the Smc, Sfc, Smt, Sfm as the standard deviation in the groups.

I caculated MRR=Xmt/Xmc, FRR=Fmt/Fmc as the response ratios in the studies and plan to do meta-analysis based on them.

Since what I really what to see is that if male and females responsed differently.
So can I compare MRR/FRR and make it another response ratio?

In that way, I don't think I have the n or SD, so how can I get the v for meta-analysis? Or is it totally a wrong idea?

Comment: You could use test for subgroup significance by setting them as two subgroups (males; females). It will give you a p-value and I-squared. https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_9/9_6_3_1_is_the_effect_different_in_different_subgroups.htm